# Regular expression to match pattern followed by / and then a specific set of words

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds

I have a string like this

`x/variable`

Since the x in the above string could be of any word followed by / followed 
by variable or expression. How to write a regex for this i tried the below

`[^/]*["variable"||"expression"]`

in this [website](https://regex101.com/r/Rt5cMp/1/). but it's not working. How to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try below

> ^\w+/(variable|expression)

As you said `x` mean any value followed by `/` followed by `variable` or `expression`.

`^\w` - will match any word (started on the line = `^`)

`\/` - will match `/`

`(variable|expression)`  - will match variable OR expression.

https://regex101.com/r/ooQlcl/1